# import text from txt separated by brackets into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a txt file with data written from an api request where each entry is bracketed, like this:

[1514780160000, '13329.00000000', '13330.00000000', '13323.55000000', '13330.00000000', '11.49322200', 1514780219999, '153192.57770167', 68, '9.55175200', '127322.45754008', '0'], [1514780220000, '13330.00000000', '13389.98000000', '13328.90000000', '13335.05000000', '9.00107100', 1514780279999, '120042.83181642', 84, '5.78463600', '77160.15209041', '0']

how do I read this into pandas dataframe with read csv as when I try splitting by brackets it gives me an error? Thank you.

Cheers,

Comment: What error it gives?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: sorry it's a warning not an error - it says "parser warning" failure to support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+'

Comment: the data cannot be used

Comment: sorry the coder is Chinese i'm translating so there are some delays

Comment: What command are you using to read the file?

Comment: Yup not a problem

Comment: What command are you using to read the file? Can you tell this

Comment: @thenightisdark welcome to `Stackoverflow` community. kindly advise if the `txt` file is one line ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('ss.txt', header=None)

print(data)
```

Or:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

with open('ss.txt') as f:
    res = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
    print(pd.DataFrame(res))
```

Comment: How `|` will help here?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah what?

Comment: how pipeline will resolve the issue here? could you explain your code?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah just removed it (typed by mistake). if the file is one line so he will need to iterate then append and read.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

f=open('s1.txt')
res = list(ast.literal_eval(f.read()))
print(pd.DataFrame(res))
f.close()
```

O/P:

```
              0               1  ...               10 11
0  1514780160000  13329.00000000 ...  127322.45754008  0
1  1514780220000  13330.00000000 ...   77160.15209041  0

[2 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: `f=open('s1.txt')` ! you need to close the file then or use `with open('s1.txt', 'r') as f:`

Comment: I've removed my answer as well. looks like the `OP` text file is one line.

Comment: why you are using `list` here ! it's not make sense at all !

Comment: It throws `ValueError`

Comment: that's incorrect, [check](https://i.ibb.co/tD15fmX/Capture.png)

Comment: it seems we are working on different pandas version :)

Comment: I appreciate your effort. It would be great, if you provide alternative answer to the problem.